# Is it possible to merge changes on server using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automation, jenkins-plugins

I am looking for a way to merge full local directory to a remote server using jenkins. It is easy to use some FTP plugin to delete while remote directory and re-upload all the files, but i would like to only upload new/changed files and remove the deleted files.

Is it possible to do that using jenkins? Maybe some other automation tool?

Comment: You mean something like doing a `git push`

Comment: mmm.. sort of. But: 1. we use SVN. 2. I can't perform pull/upadte to the server because it does not have access to the SVN repository (it resides on a server that is accessible only from the company domain)

Comment: Which OS is jenkins running on? If on linux, you can use `rsync`

Comment: Yes, we are using linux. I will check out the rsync plugin. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

On Unix or Linux you can run 'rsync' with the two directories as parameters -
either on the local or on the remote host.

Just make sure you are not in the middle of some other operation while 'rsync' runs.